# Unable to Localize Custom Keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-keyboard-extension

I am trying to implement a keyboard extension, which can display keys depending upon the language chosen by the user in Settings of the device.

In **Edit Scheme**, I have correctly setup the *Application Language* and *Application Region* for both Container app and extension as shown:

[image]

But still my keyboard always open up in English(en-US) version.

In **info.plist**, I have already added **mul** for *PrimaryLanguage*:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>IsASCIICapable</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PrefersRightToLeft</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
            <string>mul</string>
            <key>RequestsOpenAccess</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
```

Moreover, I have localized key names.

[image]

I logged what language is being interpreted by app using:

```
    var lang : String = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as! String
    NSLog(lang)
```

Container app does detect correct language as **ur**. But keyboard Extension always picks up **en-US**. I am using xcode 6.4 and testing on Simulator iOS 8.4.

I am probably missing out a very small point here. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, found the solution. I was doing Localization in wrong way. Correct way is to keep **English** as *First language for base*, then other languages should follow along.

[image]

Moreover, in order to detect language correctly in simulator (for keyboard), you should also change **Language and Region** in the simulator along with **Schema**.

[image]

Hope it helps someone in future!